# Why is the play button on my title screen not starting the game?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I managed to open the demo game that I need to see/play, however, it looks like the title screen isn't loading correctly. Clicking on the "Play" button should allow the user to start the game, but when I try clicking on it, nothing happens.

I'm not sure why this is happening because I downloaded the exact same files as the ones that were used in the demo and I also tried deleting/redownloading the files a couple of times. I also double checked the console messages and there aren't any errors/warnings for any scripts. I'll attach a screenshot of what I see and the link to the game files themselves if anyone wants to try it on their end.

Also, if this helps, I'm using Unity version 2018.3.2f1.

Here is a link to the project if you want to try it out yourself (I'd post the code, but I don't want to put a giant block of code up without a clear direction; however, I believe the main menu content is in the "Manager.cs" file): https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ekXt948b612dmyT1AZReUOuzh2XbnSDG/view?usp=sharing

This is what the game looks like if it helps:
[image]

Comment: Could you please add some code snippets? (Just the bits pertaining to the button etc.) Or just pastebin them so we can see them without needing to download the whole project. People like me use their phones sometimes ;)

Comment: Do you need to click somewhere within the game to get it to start after clicking the play button?

Comment: @TheChubbyPanda Will do! Let me do some digging really quick!

Comment: @BenRubin Huh, that's a good suggestion, I'll also give that a try :D

Comment: There is nothing about the main menu in the `Manager.cs` file that I can see.

Comment: Oh wow, I figured it out. Turns out it was because the developer was using a specific "hitbox" with canvas position/specific width & height position. So since I was using the wrong aspect ratio/canvas size, the hitbox wasn't in the right place. And I also figured out that it was actually in a different script, sorry about that @TheChubbyPanda! And thanks to everyone else who helped!

Comment: No problem, if you add that as an answer, I'm sure it'll help someone out at some point. I'll be sure to upvote it!

Answer (score 0):

After reading through the code in the other scripts, I realized that the error was coming from the specific region that was being used as a "hitbox" on the screen for the play button. And because I was setting my aspect ratio differently than what the developer used, the positioning of the "hitbox" did not line up correctly on my screen. So instead, I had to change the aspect ratio to fixed resolution and specific canvas sizes (width and length).